# AngularJS + ui-router - lightbox overlay with deep links

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to use AngularJS to create a lightbox which contains url deeplinks. This works fine, but I need to name it for every page I want it to work on with the template behind it.

I can get this to work using ui-router and named views:

```
<ul>
    <li><a ui-sref="home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a ui-sref="portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
    <li><a ui-sref="videos">Videos</a></li>
</ul>
<div ui-view></div>
<div ui-view="overlay"></div>
```

And the javascript:

```
    $stateProvider
        .state('home', {
            url: '/',
            controller: 'HomeCtrl',
            templateUrl: 'html/Home.html'
        })
        .state('portfolio', {
            url: '/portfolio/:id',
            controller: 'PortfolioCtrl',
            templateUrl: 'html/Portfolio.html'
        })
        .state('videos', {
            views: {
                'overlay@': {
                    controller: 'VideosCtrl',
                    templateUrl: 'html/Videos.html'
                }
            }
        });
```

Expected behaviour:
- click home, then click videos = shows videos overlay on home
- click portfolio, then click videos = shows videos overlay on portfolio page

Actual behaviour:
- click home, then click videos = shows videos overlay with blank page behind
- click portfolio, then click videos = shows videos overlay with blank page behind

Is there a way to have the named view update on any page leaving the existing ui-view intact?

Answer (score 1):

You might look into using a modal for videos instead of the router if you want to overlay it on top of multiple states.  If you stick with using the router, you might want to define videos as a child state of both home and portfolio instead of defining three states at the same level.